# Transparent proxy with CA-Signed certificates

Tags: ssl, https, proxy, transparent, squid

Is this possible?
My understanding goes as far as this:
A non-proxy aware client will negotiate SSL directly with a listener, without every sending a CONNECT request to identify the destination host. A transparent proxy would need a destination host in order to forge a certificate with the hostname for the client.

I've read that some browser support the "server_name" extension in the client hello message which will identify the destination host and that if the extension is present this can be done. However, I'm unaware which browsers if any support this extension.

I would think that this should be possible but my efforts so far using squid and burp haven't been successful.

I understand that there's no way to obtain the destination host in the initial connection phase but I would think that with the correct configuration it would be possible to allow a forwarded connection in the initial phase then capture the returned certificate in order to read the destination then be able to inject the proxy's own CA-signed certificate at this point with the hostname derived from the legitimate certificate.

I think the best bet to get this working (if it's at all possible) is using squid's bump-server-first method http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/BumpSslServerFirst

I'm interested to hear if anyone has ever successfully gotten this to work.